# About Hilbert-Haar theory

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, convex-analysis

The Hilbert-Haar theory says that functionals $\mathcal{F}(u,B)=\int_{B} F(\nabla u)\,dx$, where $F$ is a convex function and $B$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, take a minimum in the space of all Lipschitz functions in $\Omega$ with boundary value $\phi$ on $\partial B$ provided that $\phi$ satisfies a bounded slope condition.

A function $\phi:\partial B\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the bounded slope condition of rank $K$ if for any $x_0\in\partial B$ there exist vectors $l_{x_0}^-$ and $l_{x_0}^+$ satisfying $\|l_{x_0}^-\|\leq K, \|l_{x_0}^+\|\leq K$ such that
\begin{align*}
    l_{x_0}^-\cdot(x-x_0)\leq \phi(x)-\phi(x_0)\leq l_{x_0}^+\cdot(x-x_0),\mbox{ for any $x\in\partial B$.}
\end{align*}

I wanted to know if there is a version of Hilbert-Haar theory for more general functionals of the type $\mathcal{F}(u,B)=\int_{B} F(x,\nabla u)\,dx$, with sufficient smoothness in the $x$ variable.

I couldn't find a reference for this or as to why it cannot be true.